# How to have R Shiny titlepanel pull text from server?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there some way to have a dynamic titlePanel title that pulls directly from UI kind of like below?  If it's not possible, is it possible to have a second row that's similar to titlepanel right below titlepanel?

```
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  ##Whatever UI code here
  titlepanel_text = paste0("Some string", variable_with_text)
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
    titlePanel("title panel"),
   #Rest of server code here

}
```

Comment: The typical way to achieve that is through `renderUI`.

Comment: @Ameya how should I use renderUI?

Comment: Similar Q earlier yesterday, might be helpful for you too; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808905/render-title-in-r-shiny-box-dynamically/50810580#50810580

Answer (score 2):

Render the text in the server and grab the text output in the UI:

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  ##Whatever UI code here
  titlePanel(textOutput("title_panel")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(h1("text"))
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$title_panel <- renderText({
    paste0("This is the date/time: ", Sys.time() )
  })

}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert this kind of code to structure your title panel

```
 # Application title
        titlePanel(
          fixedRow(
            column(9,
                   "My Template",
                   fixedRow(
                     column(9,
                            paste0("Author : ", author)
                     ),
                     column(3,
                            paste0("date : ", today(tzone = ""))
                     )
                   )
            )
          )  ),
```